# Can't Autowire @Repository annotated interface in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, repository, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a spring boot application and I'm running into an issue here. I'm trying to inject a @Repository annotated interface and it doesn't seem to work at all. I'm getting this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springBootRunner': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.pharmacy.persistence.users.dao.UserEntityDao com.pharmacy.config.SpringBootRunner.userEntityDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.pharmacy.persistence.users.dao.UserEntityDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.pharmacy.config.SpringBootRunner.main(SpringBootRunner.java:25)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.pharmacy.persistence.users.dao.UserEntityDao com.pharmacy.config.SpringBootRunner.userEntityDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.pharmacy.persistence.users.dao.UserEntityDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.pharmacy.persistence.users.dao.UserEntityDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Here is my code:

Main application class:

```
package com.pharmacy.config;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("org.pharmacy")
public class SpringBootRunner {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootRunner.class, args);
    }
}
```

Entity class:

```
package com.pharmacy.persistence.users;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;



@Entity
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;

}
```

Repository interface:

```
package com.pharmacy.persistence.users.dao;

import com.pharmacy.persistence.users.UserEntity;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface UserEntityDao extends CrudRepository<UserEntity,Long>{

}
```

Controller:

```
package com.pharmacy.controllers;

import com.pharmacy.persistence.users.UserEntity;
import com.pharmacy.persistence.users.dao.UserEntityDao;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class HomeController {


    @Autowired
    UserEntityDao userEntityDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String hello() {
        userEntityDao.save(new UserEntity("ac"));
        return "Test";

    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
mainClassName = "com.pharmacy.config.SpringBootRunner"
jar {
    baseName = 'demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-ws")
    compile("postgresql:postgresql:9.0-801.jdbc4")

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.view.prefix: /
spring.view.suffix: .html

spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update


spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=abc123
```

I even compared my code with [Accessing data jpa](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/), and I'm running out of ideas what's wrong with this code.
Any help appreciated.

EDITED: I changed my code as suggested to look like above, and I'm not getting that error when I'm injecting my @Repository interface into another component. However, I have a problem now - my component cannot be retrieved (I used debugging). What I'm doing wrong so spring cannot find my component?

Comment: And what if you create another component and inject your 'UserEntityDao userEntityDao' to it? (also a sidenote: never inject dependencies directly to fields, use constructor with proper arguments and @Autowired/@Inject on it).

Answer (score 233):

When the repository package is different to `@SpringBootApplication`/`@EnableAutoConfiguration`, base package of `@EnableJpaRepositories` is required to be defined explicitly.

Try to add `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.pharmacy.persistence.users.dao")` to SpringBootRunner

Comment: A little old, but adding @EnableJpaRepositories on the Application class did the trick.

Comment: Strange docs says "By default, Spring Boot will enable JPA repository support and look in the package (and its subpackages) where @SpringBootApplication is located."
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: @magulla: OP's `@SpringBootApplication` located in package `com.pharmacy.config`, while `@EnableJpaRepositories` located in `com.pharmacy.persistence.users.dao`

Comment: I had this same issue. Once I specified a package for my repositories, I received another error `Entity is not a managed type`. For anyone else having this issue, You also need to add the annotation `@EntityScan("com.package.dtos")`

Comment: For MongoDB repositories add `@EnableMongoRepositories("...")`

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Note that supplying the repository package as a string will quietly break if the packages are reorganized. So a safer way to specify the repository package is `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses=MyRepository.class)`.

Comment: How does one do this when one does "Java Config" and not @ComponentScan?

Comment: I had the same issue, after applying the above solution and I removed @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class}), it working.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. Don't know why it isn't showing as the topmost answer for this question.

Comment: For Redis reposotires add `@EnableRedisRepositories("...")`

Answer (score 61):

I had the same issues with Repository not being found. So what I did was to move everything into 1 package. And this worked meaning that there was nothing wrong with my code. I moved the Repos & Entities into another package and added the following to SpringApplication class.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com...jpa")
@EntityScan("com...jpa")
```

After that, I moved the Service (interface & implementation) to another package and added the following to SpringApplication class.

```
@ComponentScan("com...service")
```

This solved my issues.

Comment: This should be the answer actually as it resolved the complete issue. as It gives `not mapped type` error after just adding `@EnableJpaRepositories`

Answer (score 52):

There is another cause for this type of problem what I would like to share, because I struggle in this problem for some time and I could't find any answer on SO.

In a repository like:

```
@Repository
public interface UserEntityDao extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, Long>{

}
```

If your entity `UserEntity` **does not have** the `@Entity` annotation on the class, you will have the same error.

This error is confusing for this case, because you focus on trying to resolve the problem about Spring not found the Repository but the problem is the entity. And if you came to this answer trying to test your Repository, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347088/spring-test-with-datajpatest-cant-autowire-class-with-repository-but-with-in/48347423#48347423) may help you.

Comment: Good shout! Thanks. For me I was using a redis repo, so defining the redish hash fixed it. e.g.
@RedisHash(LanguageMapping.KEY_NAME)

Comment: This hint saved my day! Thanx a lot! I only had a wrong import so the typing of the repository was incompatible which led to the error message!

Comment: Copied the same still with the SAME ERROR

Answer (score 16):

It seems your `@ComponentScan` annotation is not set properly.
Try :

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.pharmacy"})
```

Actually you do not need the component scan if you have your main class at the top of the structure, for example directly under `com.pharmacy` package.

Also, you don't need both

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation includes `@EnableAutoConfiguration` by default.

Comment: Actually `@ComponentScan("com.pharmacy")` should do.

Comment: "Actually you do not need the component scan if you have your main class at the top of the structure" worked for me!

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue where I was receiving `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` in Spring Boot (basically while working on CRUD repository), I had to put the below annotations on the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication   
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"<base package name>"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="<repository package name>")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages="<entity package name>")
```

Also, make sure you have the `@Component` annotations in place on the implementations.

Answer (score 9):

In SpringBoot, the JpaRepository are not auto-enabled by default. You have to explicitly add

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("packages")
@EntityScan("packages")
```

Comment: Same issue I was facing, I had Repo and Entity in a library project, which was added as a dependency in an application project. There in the App.java need to enable these explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, I had same issue as @FrancisRaj and after adding both `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` with full package path, I could use my library project to connect with database

Answer (score 6):

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages=,<youur package name>)
@EnableJpaRepositories(<you jpa repo package>)
@EntityScan(<your entity package>)

Entity class like below 
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25726062)

Answer (score 5):

To extend onto above answers, You can actually add more than one package in your EnableJPARepositories tag, so that you won't run into "Object not mapped" error after only specifying the repository package.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.test.model", "com.test.repository"})
public class SpringBootApplication{

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are scanning the wrong package:

```
@ComponentScan("**org**.pharmacy")
```

Where as it should be:

```
@ComponentScan("**com**.pharmacy")
```

Since your package names start with com and not org.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved that issue by changing that dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

With that one :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In that way there is no need to use Anotations like :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"controller", "service"})
@EntityScan("entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("repository")
```

)

Comment: After hours of trying to figure it out, this solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It could be to do with the package you have it in. I had a similar problem:

```
Description:
Field userRepo in com.App.AppApplication required a bean of type 'repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type '`repository.UserRepository`' in your configuration.
"

Solved it by put the repository files into a package with standardised naming convention:

```
e.g. com.app.Todo (for main domain files)
```

and

```
com.app.Todo.repository (for repository files)
```

That way, spring knows where to go looking for the repositories, else things get confusing really fast. :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with Spring Data MongoDB: I had to add the package path to `@EnableMongoRepositories`

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems with this topic too.
You have to make sure you define the packages in Spring boot runner class like this example below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"controller", "service"})
@EntityScan("entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("repository")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the mistake: as someone said before, you are using org.pharmacy insted of com.pharmacy in componentscan

```
    package **com**.pharmacy.config;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan("**org**.pharmacy")
    public class SpringBootRunner {
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as previous answer

Answer (score 2):

If you're facing this problem when unit testing with `@DataJpaTest` then you'll find the solution below.

Spring boot do not initialize `@Repository` beans for `@DataJpaTest`. So try one of the two fix below to have them available:

**First**

Use `@SpringBootTest` instead. But this will boot up the whole application context.

**Second**(Better solutions)

Import the specific repository you need, like below

```
@DataJpaTest
@Import(MyRepository.class)
public class MyRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private MyRepository myRepository;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but with a different cause:

In my case the problem was that in the interface defining the repository

```
public interface ItemRepository extends Repository {..}
```

I was omitting the types of the template. Setting them right:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends Repository<Item,Long> {..}
```

did the trick.

Comment: Awesome. Only solution that helped me fix the issue;

Answer (score 1):

In `@ComponentScan("org.pharmacy")`, you are declaring **`org.pharmacy`** package.
But your components in **`com.pharmacy`** package.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the answer up there help a lot, because they are part of the whole solution. For me it was a mix of some of them.

Your `ComponentScan` package is wrong. Change it to:

```
@ComponentScan("com.pharmacy")
```

You also have to add:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
```

to your `SpringBootApplication` class, here: `SpringBootRunner`.

I had to change the Maven dependency (works similarly for Gradle):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Don't forget to refresh your dependencies.

Then I also had to change my imports in my `Entity` class to:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `@Service` or `@Component` that is trying to auto-wire the repository isn't in the same directory as your `SpringApplication.class`. Make sure it's in a subfolder like `service/`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I had the same issues when I forget to add Lombok annotation processor dependency to the maven configuration

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below dependency on pom.xml solved the problem

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your main class is in com.example package your other class should which are in different packages should be called in com.example package;
i.e:Controller package
com.example.controller

AND

Your Main class should be in com.example not in com.example.main
if you gave the main class package as com.example.main then the other should be within that package e.g com.package.main.controller

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might be using Spring Data JPA in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Try replacing it with Spring Boot Starter Data JPA. It has all the necessary dependencies to fix the repository loading issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```