# Spring Boot Unit Testing - Test fails complaining about not having an "entityManagerFactory" bean defined

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mockito

I'm trying to write a unit test for a Controller in a Spring Boot application. The application runs smoothly, my problem is with running its **tests**.

Here is the test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager
public class MyControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
private MyRepository myRepository;

@Mock
ZendeskNotifier zendeskNotifier;

@Mock
ActivityLogger activityLogger;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void cannotSendFooWithoutMessageBody() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/foo/1/send"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError())
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("The message body cannot be empty.")));
}
}
```

When I try running it I get:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field jobEventRepository in foo.bar.util.memsource.svc.MemsourceEventProcessor required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

And that feels weird to me, since I'm providing the `AutoConfigureTestEntityManager` annotation and would expect all the `EntityManager`-related stuff to be in place.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, did you manage to solve this eventually? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, actually, no. :( I've already left that job and as far as I know they never got it working (they never really were into the TDD boat anyway)

Answer (score 3):

If Google brought you here and you're using Spring Boot, you may need to add `@DataJpaTest` to your test class. It's found in `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure`. You may also discover upon rerunning that you need to declare a dependency on `org.hibernate:hibernate-validator`.

Comment: But why do I need to add @DataJpaTest to a controller test? I've created completely empty controller with completely empty test and it still fails with "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available". Why? :( Edit: also, you can't have both \@WebMvcTest and \@DataJpaTest.

Comment: @Dalibor Thanks for that comment about the empty test - it helped me figure out the answer, which is that your application's configuration (and mine) were being found and used by the unit tests. I posted an answer with a full explanation, and ways to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot is loading your application's configuration, causing your data layer to be initialized.

Excerpt from Spring Boot's docs, [Detecting Test Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config):

> Spring Boot’s @*Test annotations search for your primary configuration
>   automatically **whenever you do not explicitly define one**.
>
> The search algorithm works up from the package that contains the test
>   until it finds a class annotated with @SpringBootApplication or
>   @SpringBootConfiguration. As long as you structured your code in a
>   sensible way, your main configuration is usually found.

When the scanning hits your `main` class it is likely finding an annotation like `@EnableJpaRepositories`, which initializes your data layer and thus requires the entity manager factory. (You may see other side effects too, like Hibernate initializing your in-memory database if your application uses one.)

As other answers suggest, you could initialize the data layer, or try to wire/mock the missing beans. But since you aren't testing the data layer here it would be better to control the test's configuration.

The docs suggest some solutions:

1. Move `@EnableJpaRepositories` from the main class to a config class in child package. It will get scanned by the application (from the top package down) but not by the unit tests. This is discussed in the section [User Configuration and Slicing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-user-configuration).
2. Add a nested `@Configuration` class to override the configuration used by the unit test.

The first one seems like a good rule to follow in general. Other annotations like `@EnableBatchProcessing` and `@EnableScheduling` can be treated the same way, which will speed up your unit tests.

Comment: Note that if you move @EnableJpaRepositories to a config class you will probably run into a different problem when you run the app, which is your repositories suddenly not autowiring. Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209023/2436878

Answer (score 2):

I found out that there is an Annotation you can use to add JPA-Support to your WebMVCTest **(@AutoConfigureDataJpa)**

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SurchargesTestConfiguration.class })
@WebMvcTest(SurchargesApiController.class)
@AutoConfigureDataJpa
@ActiveProfiles("local")
class SurchargesApiControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    void testNotFound() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/surcharges/marketnumber") //
                .headers(getDefaultHeaders())) //
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inject Spring's `TestEntityManager` in your `mockito` test class.

```
@Autowired
private TestEntityManager entityManager;
```

You are already using `@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager` on the test class to auto configure this test entity manager. So you don't have to do anything else in the config file.

Comment: I tried autowiring both `TestEntityManager` and also `EntityManagerFactory` and got the exact same result as described above. :(

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure `entityManagerFactory`, you can refer bellow code

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="packagesToScan" value="org.demo.test.entity" />
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

<property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
    </props>
</property>

<property name="persistenceProvider">
    <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider">
</bean>
</property>

</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move @EnableJpaRepositories from the main class to a config class in a child package. It will get scanned by the application (from the top package down) but not by the unit tests.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    value = "com.company.repository"
)
public class JpaConfig {
}
```

Comment: Please tend to give an explanation along with code as well as a good practice and for better understanding.