# Repository annotation is not working on Spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am building a Spring-boot application where I am using Spring data jpa feature.

Please find below my dao layer code

```
package com.adv.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CustomerDao extends JpaRepository<Customer, String> {

}
```

I am using a DaoProvider class as follows:

```
package com.adv.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class DaoProvider implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

@Autowired
private CustomerDao customerDao;

public CustomerDao getCustomerDao() {
    return customerDao;
}
}
```

My spring boot main class is defined as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.adv")
public class AdvMain extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(AdvMain.class);
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(AdvMain.class, args);
    }
 }
```

Now during runtime I am getting following exception:

```
Field customerDao in com.adv.dao.DaoProvider required a bean of type 'com.adv.dao.CustomerDao' that could not be found.
```

I guess that `@Repository` annotation on interface `CustomerDao` is not working.

But I am unable to figure out the issue.Can anyone figure out the problem?

Comment: Try to add `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.adv.dao")` on `AdvMain` as suggested on [Can't Autowire @Repository annotated interface in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221645/cant-autowire-repository-annotated-interface-in-spring-boot)

Comment: ok.thanks.It worked after adding @EnableJpaRepositories("com.adv.dao")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.adv.dao")` on `AdvMain` as suggested by @hang321 on [Can't Autowire @Repository annotated interface in Spring Boot
Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221645/cant-autowire-repository-annotated-interface-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the annotation @Repository from the dao interface. That annotation must be put only on implented classes.

Be careful also to implement both the empty constructor than the all args constructor of the Customer class.

Comment: No Alex.We require this Repository annotation at interface level while working with JpaRepository.It is little different than other normal interfaces.Whatever you have pointed out is suitable for all other user defiend interfaces.

Comment: I always use without the annotation @Repository and it works perfectly. I know it's not a normal interface, still the real bean is implemented by Spring, so Spring knows it's a repo bean.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `@ComponentScan` annotation altogether.The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation already includes the component scan as specified [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html).

Comment: ComponentScan is required since I have package segregation for various classes.By deault spring scan only the package in which main class is located.anyways the answer to my problem was use of EnableJpaRepositories.