# SpringBoot scanBasePackages does not find repository in different jar

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application like this:

```
package my.package;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.activemq.ActiveMQAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have a service in the package `my.package.service`

```
@Service
public class MyService {

private ServiceInADifferentJar  dep;

public MySerivce(ServiceInADifferentJar dep) {
this.dep = dep;
}

}
```

The class `ServiceInADifferentJar` is an `@Service` annotated class in a different JAR, which I include as a maven dependency.

The JAR Has this file structure:

```
src/main/java
- some.package.repository
    MyRepository.java
- some.package.service
    ServiceInADifferentJar.java
```

`MyRepository` is an `@Repository` annotated interface that extends a Spring Data inerface.

`ServiceInADifferentJar` gets `MyRepository` injected in its constructor.

WHen I start the application, I get an error that `ServiceInADifferentJar` cannot be found.

Then I added this to my SpringBootApp

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"some.package"})
```

and`ServiceInADifferentJar` is found, but not `MyRepository`.

Why not? Why aren't all sub-packages of `some.package` in the other JAR scanned?

*** EDIT ***

The repository

```
package some.package.repository;

    @Repository
    public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<SomeEntity, String> {

    }
```

Comment: Could you add your repository interface ?

Comment: @Berger I edited my question

Comment: Are you building with Maven?

Comment: @TheHeadRush yes, both are maven projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use the [EnableMongoRepositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/config/EnableMongoRepositories.html) annotation, so that your Mongo repository gets found .

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "some.package.repository")
```

The following question, despite being about JPA repositories, has some more explanation about how repositories scanning work :

[Can't Autowire @Repository annotated interface in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221645/cant-autowire-repository-annotated-interface-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I am a little surprised that Spring actually needs these kind of explicit pointers to those packages, but well, at least it works now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

hey man you should put this in your main class after the @SpringBootApplication tag
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"some.package"})

Comment: I did that but it still cannot find the Repository.