# Spring Server Issue with Bean Creation

Tags: java, spring

I am having an issue in which a defined repository is not being correctly interpreted as a bean on server startup. The class with @SpringBootApplication is in a higher directory than the defined repository, so I cannot find why it does not configure.

@SpringBootApplication:

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    System.out.println("http://localhost:8080");
}
}
```

Repository

```
package lab14.panoslab.Repositories;

import lab14.panoslab.Models.Account;
import org.apache.catalina.User;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Account,Long> {
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
List<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Error code:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START***************************
>
> Description:
>
> Field userRepository in lab14.panoslab.Controllers.RegisterController
>   required a bean of type 'lab14.panoslab.Repositories.UserRepository'
>   that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'lab14.panoslab.Repositories.UserRepository' in your configuration.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221645/cant-autowire-repository-annotated-interface-in-spring-boot

Comment: by looking this error, in this controller class `RegisterController` you autowired `UserRepository` bean, have you declared this bean in your config? or can you post the complete code?

Comment: Just a general comment, for package names, typically they are all lowercase. 
 So this package should be lowercase.  `lab14.panoslab.Repositories`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your class `Account` implements the interface `User`?

And try to remove the annotation `@Repository` and add annotations `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` in your `DemoApplication` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan({"lab14.panoslab.Models"})    
@EnableJpaRepositories({"lab14.panoslab.Repositories"})
public class DemoApplication {...}
```

Also, I would advise you to rename all your packages into lowercase and return a value of `List<Account>`, not `List<User>`.

Answer (score 0):

I did face similar issue. What I have done the mistake is, I have placed my controller/repository and other component packages outside the Main Class package. So, Spring boot not able to identify my components,

**For Ex:** main class package is **package com.example.demo;**

Controller package like, **package com.example.controller;**

Repository package like, **package com.example.repository;**

***Below are the two different ways to solve this problem***,

Explicitly defining my component packages in @ComponentScan, like **@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.example.controller,com.example.repository")** with base packages of required components.

Otherwise, You can create Controller/repository packages inside the main package. So, you no need to define **@ComponentScan** and all.
For ex,

main class package is **package com.example.demo;**

Controller package like, **package com.example.demo.controller;**

Repository package like, **package com.example.demo.repository;**