# Spring Repository Bean Not Being Found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to do a simple CRUD in postgres with spring, but for no reason my IoD mechanism doesn't work and throws an error like this:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in br.com.maptriz.formulario_dinamico.service.FormularioDinamicoService required a bean of type 'br.com.maptriz.formulario_dinamico.repository.FormularioDinamicoRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'br.com.maptriz.formulario_dinamico.repository.FormularioDinamicoRepository' in your configuration.
```

Here's my code:

FormularioDinamicoApplication.java

```
package br.com.maptriz.formulario_dinamico;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

// @EnableJpaRepositories("br.com.maptriz.formulario_dinamico.repository")
// @EnableScheduling
// @EnableDiscoveryClient
// @ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class FormularioDinamicoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FormularioDinamicoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

FormularioDinamico

```
package br.com.maptriz.formulario_dinamico.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "formulario_dinamico")
public class FormularioDinamico {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tipo_tabela")
    private Long tabelaId;
    private String name;
    private String campos;

    protected FormularioDinamico() {}
    
    public FormularioDinamico(Long tabelaId, String name, String campos) {
        this.tabelaId = tabelaId;
        this.name = name;
        this.campos = campos;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getTabelaId() {
        return this.tabelaId;
    }

    public void setTabelaId(Long tabelaId) {
        this.tabelaId = tabelaId;
    } 

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setObservacao(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCampos() {
        return this.campos;
    }

    public void setCampos(String campos) {
        this.campos = campos;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EntidadeGenerica{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", dataAtualizacao=" + tabelaId +
                ", dataCadastro=" + name +
                ", observacao='" + campos + '}';
    }
}
```

FormlarioDinamicoController.java

```
package br.com.maptriz.formulario_dinamico.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import br.com.maptriz.formulario_dinamico.model.FormularioDinamico;
import br.com.maptriz.formulario_dinamico.service.FormularioDinamicoService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class FormularioDinamicoController {
    private final FormularioDinamicoService service;

    @Autowired
    public FormularioDinamicoController(FormularioDinamicoService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    // @GetMapping
    // public List<DynamicForm> getDynamicForm() {
    //     return dynamicFormService.getDynamicForm();
    // }
    
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public void registrarNovoFormularioDinamico(@RequestBody FormularioDinamico formularioDinamico) {
        System.out.println("TEST");
        service.adicionarNovoFormularioDinamico(formularioDinamico);
    }
}
```

FormularioDinamicoService.java

```
package br.com.maptriz.formulario_dinamico.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import br.com.maptriz.formulario_dinamico.model.FormularioDinamico;
import br.com.maptriz.formulario_dinamico.repository.FormularioDinamicoRepository;

@Service
public class FormularioDinamicoService {
    
    private final FormularioDinamicoRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public FormularioDinamicoService(FormularioDinamicoRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    // public List<DynamicForm> getDynamicForm() {
    //  return dynamicFormRepository.findAll();
    // }

    public void adicionarNovoFormularioDinamico(FormularioDinamico formularioDinamico) {
        List<FormularioDinamico> topicos = repository.findAll();
        System.out.println("HEREEEE");
        System.out.println(topicos);
    }
}
```

And finally FormularioDinamicoRepository.java

```
package br.com.maptriz.formulario_dinamico.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import br.com.maptriz.formulario_dinamico.model.FormularioDinamico;



public interface FormularioDinamicoRepository
        extends JpaRepository<FormularioDinamico, Long> {

    List<FormularioDinamico> findAll();
}
```

My Folder Structure:

- src

  - main

    - java/br/com/maptriz/formulario_dinamico

      - controller
      - model
      - repository
      - service
      - FormularioDinamicoApplication.java

Comment: For starters ditch the `findAll` as that is already part of the default methods on `JpaRepository`. You also don't need the `@Autowired` on the constructors in case of a single constructor (not that that solves your issue, but cleans your code a little). Run your app with `--debug` to get a stack trace on what is wrong. I suspect something wrong in your database or JPA configuration in your `application.properties` or a missing database.

Answer (score 1):

Add `@Repository` annotation on the interface `FormularioDinamicoRepository`. It should be working seamlessly.

The moment you add it spring identifies it as a bean and creates an object and injects the bean wherever autowired.

Comment: Adding that annotation on a Spring Data JPA repository is useless and is only clutter. Spring Data JPA has other ways of detecting its repositories.

Comment: Hi M. Deinum, Could you please specify what should otherwise be added to bypass the exception? what exactly do you mean by clutter and if so why had spring given the annotation. I personally feel the annotation would have been deprecated way back had it really been a clutter.

Comment: It adds clutter to a Spring Data repository not if you write your own repository implementation. You are mixing different things. Adding annotations to interfaces is generally pretty useless as they don't propagate to the implementation classes anyway.

Comment: see response here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221645/cant-autowire-repository-annotated-interface-in-spring-boot