# Parameter 0 of constructor requied a bean of type that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot

I have following project structure:

[image]

If I try to run application, it's give me:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in
> notifications.service.NotificationService required a bean of type
> 'notifications.dao.NotificationDAO' that could not be found.

I tried with many variations of Lombok constructors annotations and it doesnt work
my service class:

```
package notifications.service;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import notifications.dao.NotificationDAO;
import notifications.model.NotificationEntity;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NotificationService {


  private final NotificationDAO notificationDAO;

  public List<NotificationEntity> findByUserId(Long userId) {
    return notificationDAO.findAllByUserId(userId,Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "id"));
 }

  public List<NotificationEntity> findAllByUserIdAndApplicationId(Long userId, Long applicationId) {
    return notificationDAO.findAllByUserIdAndApplicationId(userId, applicationId, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "id"));
 }

  public List<NotificationEntity> findAllByUserIdAndDocumentId(Long userId, Long documentId) {
    return notificationDAO.findAllByUserIdAndDocumentId(userId, documentId, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "id"));
 }
}
```

dao:

```
package notifications.dao;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import notifications.model.NotificationEntity;

import java.util.List;


@Repository
public interface NotificationDAO extends JpaRepository<NotificationEntity, Long> {

    List<NotificationEntity> findAllByUserId(Long userId, Sort sort);

    List<NotificationEntity> findAllByUserIdAndApplicationId(Long userId, Long applicationId, Sort sort);

    List<NotificationEntity> findAllByUserIdAndDocumentId(Long userId, Long documentId, Sort sort);

}
```

main class:

```
package notifications;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.config.EnableR2dbcRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
public class NotificationsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NotificationsApplication.class, args);
    }
```

}

Do You see any suggestions what is wrong here?

Comment: Show your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, also why do you have a `DatabaseConfig` this feels like interfering with the Spring Boot auto-configuration. Please add that to your question as well.

Comment: main class added

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't Autowire @Repository annotated interface in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221645/cant-autowire-repository-annotated-interface-in-spring-boot)

Comment: @mtmx Is lombok correctly installed and configured?
It is him that creates the constructor in NotificationService that will inject your repository

Comment: @Easterwood - I dont use Autowired, that's different problem

Comment: @pochopsp, I have lombok as plugin and in pom.xml

Comment: maybe I need some @ComponentScan here?

Comment: @mtmx your right, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you want to use JPA or R2DBC but you have mixed up both. First your interface extends from `JpaRepository` so you need to add the `@EnableJpaRepositories`. This will instruct spring to create a JPA based bean for your `NotificationDAO`.

The annotation `@EnableR2dbcRepositories` at `NotificationsApplication` looks for repositories extending `ReactiveCrudRepository` which isn't the case in your code.

Comment: ok, now I have 'reactive types expected' in my DAO, so that's the point, thanks

Comment: Remove the `@Enable*` you have now, Spring Boot will auto-detect this based upon your dependencies.

Comment: Ok, I changed to ReactiveCrudRepository, changed List to Flux, removed @Enabler2dbc and still have 'Parameter 0 of constructor in notifications.service.NotificationService required a bean of type 'notifications.dao.NotificationDAO' that could not be found.'

Comment: ok, i removed jpa from pom.xml and move from jpa to Spring annotations in my entity - like @ Table @ Column

Comment: Please update you question with your changes. Perhaps in a separate Update part.