# issue with Could not autowire. No beans of 'String' type found

Tags: java, maven, microservices, spring-boot-maven-plugin

so ive been looking up on diffrent solutions for the problem, im using intelij idea, what im tryng to do is set up microservices where my order service communicates to product service via API-Gateway, later on im thinking to set opp rabbitmq for this. but ive stumbled across this issue. i dont understand what its not happy about.

```
package no.kristiania.orderservice.order.service;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import no.kristiania.orderservice.order.entity.Order;
import no.kristiania.orderservice.order.repository.OrderRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OrderServiceIMPL implements OrderService {

    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${gateway.url}")
    private String gatewayUrl; // Changed to private - the issue is on gatewayUrl

    @Override
    public Order createOrder(Order order) {
        // Check if the car is available by making a request to the product service through the gateway
        ResponseEntity<Boolean> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(gatewayUrl + "/api/products/" + order.getCarId() + "/availability", Boolean.class);
        boolean isCarAvailable = Boolean.TRUE.equals(response.getBody());

        if (!isCarAvailable) {
            // Handle scenario where car is not available (e.g., throw an exception or return null)
            return null;
        }

        // Car is available, create the order
        return orderRepository.save(order);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/ahadius/MikroExam   - github im using.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZGmU.png)

when i check value above the issue it does indeed get the port and localhost url of the gateway..

error i get when i try to run the springboot. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihleA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `@AllArgsConstructor` which generates the constructor with three arguments including `gatewayUrl`. But the `@Value` annotation is not propagated to the argument, that's why you see that error. Simply change `@AllArgsConstructor` to `@RequiredArgsConstructor`

Comment: it did help with error but i still got other errors tho, thanks for the quick response =)

Comment: Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-02-29T16:02:01.952+01:00 ERROR 15988 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 



Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in no.kristiania.orderservice.order.service.OrderServiceIMPL required a bean of type 'no.kristiania.orderservice.order.repository.OrderRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'no.kristiania.orderservice.order.repository.OrderRepository' in your configuration.

Comment: this is the error im still stuck with, i cant seem to find solution for it.

Comment: with Spring Boot it should work if you have added `data-jpa` starter. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221645/cant-autowire-repository-annotated-interface-in-spring-boot maybe any of the answers will help