# I'm trying to set up a service Order (microservice). but I get a error bean type constantly

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, microservices

[image: img]

So I'm trying for dear life to fix this issue with no proper fixes for it... each time I run Spring Boot I encounter this error, I have tried everything I have in power with no help. IDK if it's the compiler or me just going crazy.

```
package no.kristiania.orderservice.order.service;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import no.kristiania.orderservice.order.entity.Order;
import no.kristiania.orderservice.order.entity.OrderRequest;
import no.kristiania.orderservice.order.repository.OrderRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrderServiceIMPL {

    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${gateway.url}")
    private String gatewayUrl;

    public Order createOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest) {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setCarId(orderRequest.getCarId());
        orderRepository.save(order);

        ResponseEntity<Boolean> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(gatewayUrl + "/api/products/" + order.getCarId() + "/availability", Boolean.class);
        boolean isCarAvailable = Boolean.TRUE.equals(response.getBody());

        if (!isCarAvailable) {
            // Handle scenario where car is not available
            return null;
        }

        return order;
    }
}
```

and the `OrderConfig` which my compiler has issues with

```
package no.kristiania.orderservice.order.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Configuration
public class OrderConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

I'm willing to try any suggestions so feel free to lecture me XD.
Oh yeah almost forgot GitHub I'm using https://github.com/ahadius/MikroExam

Comment: Please add the error you are experiencing here as a text instead of sending images

Comment: Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-02-29T17:18:00.591+01:00 ERROR 12124 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe is the way you are handling dependency injection.
Try the following code, removing the @RequiredArgsConstructor and using the @Autowired annotations:

```
@Service
public class OrderServiceIMPL {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, Spring boot context is unable to inject repository object.
Please update your service as below

```
    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setOrderRepository(OrderRepository orderRepository){
          this.orderRepository = orderRepository; 
    }
```

Comment: i tried it and with no help, samme issue =/

Comment: Can you post actual error message also why are you using @RequiredArgsConstructor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78081385/issue-with-could-not-autowire-no-beans-of-string-type-found/78081758#78081758 because of this post i had another issue. the error message: Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-02-29T17:28:19.938+01:00 ERROR 20212 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

Comment: Parameter 0 of method setOrderRepository in no.kristiania.orderservice.order.service.OrderServiceimpl required a bean of type 'no.kristiania.orderservice.order.Repository.OrderRepository' that could not be found.

Comment: Can you update the question with "OrderRepository" and main application code to better understand your problem?